# How to implement polar codes on MSP430 in CCS?

Tags: msp430, error-correction

I am working on error correction codes. I want to know, is it possible to implement [polar codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_code_(coding_theory)) on [MSP430FR5994](https://www.ti.com/product/MSP430FR5994)?

---

Actually, I wanted to confirm its feasibility for small devices, namely sensor tags cc2650 and MSP430. I want to use the polar codes for constructing the [SRAM based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Types_of_physical_unclonable_function#SRAM_PUF) [PUF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_unclonable_function)s. Polar codes will do the error correction and after that AES and/or hashing will be employed for generating a shared secret key. For polar codes, the block size will at least be 1024 bits and the operation needs to be fast, in 5 - 10 milliseconds. So I was concerned if all these objectives are achievable on MSP430FR5994 launchpad?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Keep in mind that *"Is it possible ...?"* is a yes/no question. In this case, the answer is "Yes". If you're asking us to design it for you, that would be too broad. You would need to specify something about the level of performance you expect as well as what constraints you have on the implementation. What is your specific question?

Comment: @DaveTweed thanks for your reply. Actually I wanted an answer in yes/no to confirm its feasibility for small devices namely sensor tags cc2650 and MSP430. I want to use the polar codes for constructing the SRAM based PUFs. Polar codes will do the error correction and after that AES and/or hashing will be employed for generating a shared secret key. For polar codes, the block size will at least be 1024 bits and the operation needs to be fast in (5- 10) milliseconds. So I was concerned if all these objectives are achievable on MSP430FR5994 launchpad?